# two spheros and a droid

Tags: android, sphero-api

is it possible to pair two Spheros (2.0) with one android device at the same time? So I could hold one in my hand using it as a controller/joystick for the other one rolling around. Does the API provide all building blocks to achieve this?

TIA, Thomas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of right now, the Sphero Android API does support multiple Sphero connections.

As a tip to make your life easier while doing this, use the Sphero object as opposed to the Deprecated static methods following the format "Command.sendCommand".

Answer (score 0):

You can use an open source robotic framework like http://artoo.io or http://cylonjs.com to control 2 or more spheros at the same time and combine them with other devices. It also has a REST api you could use from your phone.